# Writting the contents of an array to a text file

Tags: cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to take the contents of an array and save that data into a text file and then email that file. The text file shows up on the email screen, but when I actually receive the email, nothing is attached. I'm not getting any errors, but I'm also not sure that my data is actually being written into my text file.

```
        // create text file
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EmailSignUpData"
                                                         ofType:@"txt"];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                  error:&error];

        // write  the contents of the array into the text file to send
        [personArray writeToFile:data atomically:YES];


        // attach the text file
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/plain"    
                                         fileName:@"EmailSignUpData.txt"];
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: You have this all messed up. You get the path, then you load the contents of the file into a string. You then use that string as the filename for writing an array. That makes no sense. Why do you read a text file but then try to write an array? What do you really want to send as an attachment? The array as a text file or the contents of the "EmailSignupData.txt" file from the resource bundle?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm new to this so this is a learning as I go process. I wrote a small app the collects some data and sends that data as a plist using the messages framework. Plist list are not all that useful for someone without xcode to use, so I thought I would try my hand at converting the data in the array that the plist saves and instead of sending at plist send the data as a text file. Maybe I haven't fully understood how to create and use a text file. Right now my array is just comprised of nsStrings, so I thought I would be able to save them into a text document...?

Comment: What is in the `EmailSugnupData.txt` file in the resource bundle? How is that related to sending the contents of the `personArray` as an email attachment?

Comment: I was trying to create a text file, and then save the data from an array into the text file. So maybe I'm not even creating the text file in the correct manner. The object here is to send the text file as an attachment, not the array.

Comment: I think you are contradicting yourself. If you want to send the text file (the read-only, shipped as-is with your app, text file from the resource bundle), then why did your code attempt to write the array to a file? Forget what you have at the moment. What is your goal? Is it to send a text file representing the strings in the array or it is your goal to send the read-only text file from your app bundle named `EmailSignUpData.txt`?

Comment: Goal is this... I have a few input fields.. collect that data > save that data to a plist so that it can be used later. When the time comes to send this data out, I want to be able to attach a text file to an email, that text file would have the contents (in string format) of the array that was saved in the plist. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks. The first issue is that the app's resource bundle is read-only. You need to save the array to a different location such as the `Documents` folder. There are plenty of existing discussions on writing an `NSArray` as a plist to an appropriate folder in the app's sandbox.

Comment: Thanks, I have that part working already, I can add data save it to the plist and then call that data back into the app. The first go at this I was emailing the plist, but that seems to be not a good source of a file for someone who doesn't have xcoode, which is why I thought converting the data into a text file would be the most efficient format to email.... Does that make sense?

Comment: After taking a few days off from looking at this, it now makes sense. All I had to do was set up a new path to a .txt and writeToFile the array to the .txt file. Now I'm going to look into cleaning up the string for the text file.